# Trouble accessing class attributes in Python

Tags: python, flask, lob

I have a route in flask that I'm using to pass numerous variables into my function via http. Everything is coming in fine except for the "biz" variable. Here is my function...

```
@app.route("/sendcheck/<name>/<address_object>/<amount>/<memo>/<biz>", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def create_check(name, address_object, amount, memo, biz):
    check = lob.Check.create(
        description = 'Check for {}'.format(name),
        to_address = address_object,
        from_address = biz.address,
        bank_account = biz.bank,
        amount = amount,
        memo = memo,
        logo = open(biz_0.logo, 'rb'),
        check_bottom = '<h1 style="padding-top:4in;">{{name}}, attached is your check', #add a custom bottom
        data = {
          'name': name
        }
    )
```

The `biz` variable accesses a class with various attributes. So if the value for the variable is `biz_1` then inputting `biz.address` should be same as `biz_1.address` but it doesn't work. I'm getting...

`AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'address'`

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: No `biz` is a path segment passed in by Flask, and is *just a Unicode string*. Such a string has no attributes. `biz` is no different from `name`, `address_object` and `amount` in this respect.

Comment: apparently `biz` is not a class but a unicode object. print `biz`

Comment: Did you mean to use those path segment values to *retrieve* an instance of a specific class?

Comment: Based only on the code posted and the error, you're passing a unicode object to biz, not the object with attributes you think you are.  Post the calling code and someone can help further.

Comment: @AlanLeuthard: it's a Flask route. The arguments passed in are based on the actual URL used, matched against the route elements in `<...>` brackets. You can add type parsing to this, but there isn't any here so these are all unicode strings, guaranteed.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I understand now that I cannot access the attributes in this way. What is the cleanest way to be able to do this. Is there a way to pass the class variable `biz_1` in the URL and then access its attributes?

Comment: @freefly0313: no, there is not. You need to map an identifier for it to your objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's far from ideal but this is how I solved it. I'm open to suggestions.

```
@app.route("/sendcheck/<name>/<address_object>/<amount>/<memo>/<biz>", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def create_check(name, address_object, amount, memo, biz):
    if biz == 'biz_0':
        biz = biz_0
    elif biz == 'biz_1':
        biz = biz_1
    elif biz == 'biz_2':
        biz = biz_2
    elif biz == 'biz_3':
        biz = biz_3
    check = lob.Check.create(
        description = 'Check for {}'.format(name),
        to_address = address_object,
        from_address = biz.address,
        bank_account = biz.bank,
        amount = amount,
        memo = memo,
        logo = open(biz_0.logo, 'rb'),
        check_bottom = '<h1 style="padding-top:4in;">{{name}}, attached is your check', #add a custom bottom
        data = {
          'name': name
        }
    )
```